# Session Data is Overriding n Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am inserting the current user's username into the Session, then when the user logs out I am saving the session username data into a database table like,

```
  HttpContext.Current.Session["username"]= Username // Inserting User name
```

So, when user "James" logs into the Web Application, "James" as username is inserted into the Session at the same time as another user, "Tom", logs into the website. In Session["Username"] the name "Tom" is inserted. Up to now, this is well and good.

Now, when Tom logs out, the username "Tom" is saving into table, but when the original user "James" logs out, the Session variable is saving as "Tom" itself instead of "James". How is this possible? I am saving to the database like

```
       context.USERNAME=HttpContext.Current.SESSION["username"].ToString().
```

How is it possible, session is overriding, it should maintain separate session state, what's going wrong? Please help me anyone.

**UPDATED**

```
public class Authentication()
{
    public void AuthenticateUser(Login model)
    {
         SampleDb Context=new SampleDb(); 
         var userDetails=Context.RL_USERS
             .Where(m => m.USER_ID == userName && m.RES_TYPE == model.Type)
             .FirstOrDefault();

         HttpContext.Current.Session["username"]=userDetails.USER_NAME; //Inserting Here

    }
}
```

and when User Logout

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    string username=Session["username"].ToString()
    TrackUser user=new TrackUser()
    { 
        Username=username;
    }

    sampleDb.TrackUser.Add(user);
    sampleDb.savechanges();
}
```

Comment: In what methods do you set the sesison variable, and in what method do you save the username to the database? What exactly does your saving code look like? What is the value of `HttpContext.Current.SESSION["username"]` at that moment?

Comment: Simple like i have create a class with "Authentication" and method "UserAuthentication()", and in that i am inserting session and Action method and saving the session data.

Comment: I mean show your actual, relevant code and show from what ASP.NET methods or events are your auth methods called. The code you show doesn't cause the error you explain. Session data is session-specific.

Comment: @sanjay, Are you testing your code from same instance of browser? i.e. first you logged in with james and then in new tab you logged in with tom? It it is the case then you should try with different browser for second login.

Comment: I have updated pls check it

Comment: no, i have test with two different browsers @makwana.a

Comment: Check for SessionId i.e. Session.SessionID for both login are you getting them same?

Comment: I have tested it, it is creating separate id. @makwana.a

Comment: Try by appending SessuinId in session variable name i.e.  HttpContext.Current.Session["username" + sessionid] while setting it and while retriving it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59355/discussion-between-sanjay-and-makwana-a).

Comment: Has anyone asked how this was tested? If youre logging in from same browser yiu might have the same session which wiuld explain what is happening here